# How can I rewrite these subqueries

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery, common-table-expression

On a huge SQL query that goes like this:

```
SELECT
  ...
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table1 WHERE field = 'bar' AND table1.table0_id = table0.id)
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table1 WHERE field = 'foobar' AND table1.table0_id = table0.id)
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table1 WHERE field = 'foo' AND table1.table0_id = table0.id)
  ...
FROM table0;
```

Is there a way to avoid running the 3 queries for each iteration on table0 ?

Thanks

Comment: You definitely should to specify the PostgreSQL version. PostgreSQL growing fast and the changes even between the minor versions is significant.

Comment: @Abelisto: there are **never**  changes between "minor versions" in Postgres. A minor version is always bugfixes only, never new features or incompatible changes.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Sorry, probably I used inappropriate term. I meant 9.x where x is... (what is the name of x?)

Comment: @Abelisto: 9.x was considered a [major release](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/): "*A major release is numbered by increasing either the first or second part of the version number, e.g. 9.1 to 9.2*" - however beginning with with 10.0 this will change and the second digit **will** indicate a minor release.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Conditional Aggregation to simplify your query

Here is correct way

```
SELECT coalesce(b_count,0),
       coalesce(fb_count,0),
       coalesce(f_count,0)
FROM   table0 
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT table1.table0_id, 
                         Count(CASE WHEN field = 'bar' THEN 1 END) AS b_count, 
                         Count(CASE WHEN field = 'foobar' THEN 1 END) AS fb_count, 
                         Count(CASE WHEN field = 'foo' THEN 1 END) AS f_count, 
                  FROM   table1 
                  WHERE  field IN ( 'bar', 'foobar', 'foo' ) 
                  GROUP  BY table1.table0_id) table1 
              ON table1.table0_id = table0.id
```

Comment: BTW for the modern PostgreSQL `Count(CASE WHEN field = 'bar' THEN 1 END)` is equal to the `count(*) filter (where field = 'bar')`

Comment: @Abelisto - Can you tell the exact version where that syntax is supported so that will add in my answer

Comment: 9.4, the first appropriate link in the Google: [The FILTER clause in Postgres 9.4](https://medium.com/little-programming-joys/the-filter-clause-in-postgres-9-4-3dd327d3c852#.n7ytaa5zm)

Comment: Actually so much faster than without using a conditional aggregation, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

In Postgres 9.4+

```
select
    count(table0.id) filter (where field = 'bar'),
    count(table0.id) filter (where field = 'foobar'),
    count(table0.id) filter (where field = 'foo')
from table1
left join table0 on table1.table0_id = table0.id
group by table0.id;
```

Comment: This is not same as OP query. `Inner Join` could filter some records from `table0` when there is no match found in `table1`

Comment: Changed `INNER JOIN` to `LEFT JOIN` hope you don't mind

Comment: Let it be, however this cannot impact on `count()` but additionally gives empty rows if there are rows in `table0` not related to `table1`.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you need `table0`.  You can use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT table1.table0_id,
       SUM(CASE WHEN field = 'bar' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as bar,
       SUM(CASE WHEN field = 'foobar' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as foobar,
       SUM(CASE WHEN field = 'foo' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as foo
FROM table1
GROUP BY table1.table0_id;
```

If there are values in `table0` that are not in `table1`, you can use `left join`:

```
SELECT table2.id,
       SUM(CASE WHEN field = 'bar' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as bar,
       SUM(CASE WHEN field = 'foobar' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as foobar,
       SUM(CASE WHEN field = 'foo' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as foo
FROM table0 LEFT JOIN
     table1
     ON table0.id = table1.table0_id
GROUP BY table2.id;
```

You can also shorten the `SELECT` to:

```
       SUM((field = 'bar')::int) as bar,
       SUM((field = 'foobar')::int) as foobar,
       SUM((field = 'foo')::int) as foo
```